# Servlet exception : Method threw 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee

I'm working with this library : https://github.com/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib on my Java EE Maven Project

I got the following exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  fr.bmartel.speedtest.inter.ISpeedTestListener from [Module "deployment.vp_speedometer_war_exploded.war:main" from Service Module Loader]`

I create this Class :

```
 public class SpeedTest {

    public SpeedTest() {
        speedTestSocket = new SpeedTestSocket();
    }

    public void start() {
        //set timeout for download
        speedTestSocket.setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

        // add a listener to wait for speed examples completion and progress
        speedTestSocket.addSpeedTestListener(new ISpeedTestListener() {
            public void onProgress(final float percent, final SpeedTestReport downloadReport) {
                transfertRateBitSecond = downloadReport.getTransferRateBit(); // + " bit/second";
            }
        });

        speedTestSocket.startDownload(SPEED_TEST_SERVER_URI_DL);
    }
```

And my Servlet look like :

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        SpeedTest speedTest = new SpeedTest();
        speedTest.start();

        session.setAttribute("nbr", speedTest.getTransfertRateBitSecond());
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
}
```

It throw the exception at `SpeedTest speedTest = new SpeedTest();`
But I can't find how to solve it...

```
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/bmartel/speedtest/inter/ISpeedTestListener
    ctrl.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.bmartel.speedtest.inter.ISpeedTestListener from [Module "deployment.vp_speedometer_war_exploded.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ctrl.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:22)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Thanks for helping

---

**Edit**

Here is my pom.xml

```
<groupId>ch</groupId>
<artifactId>speedometer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://github.com/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.bmartel</groupId>
        <artifactId>jspeedtest</artifactId>
        <version>1.32.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

When I build the project, inside the "war" there is my "jspeedtest-1.13.1.jar" lib. That's ok

Comment: Are you compiling your code with the library correctly?

Comment: @Frontear Dependencies are in the library, downloaded with Maven. I need to check something else ?

Comment: @Frontear I edit my question with the content of my `pom.xml`

Comment: Does your maven include the dependency, as specified in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.bmartel/jspeedtest/1.32.1

Comment: @racraman sure (my pom.xml is above)

Comment: Just to confirm, does your end artifact (war/jar) file has the jspeedtest-1.32.1.jar within it ? I did a mock test with a spring boot and was able to see some output.

Comment: @Sachin When I build the "war" I got jspeedtest-1.31.1.jar inside, that's ok

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the problem is progressing. When I try to access to my app, I got this...

```
  13:04:21,652 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-15) Failed to define class ctrl.Servlet in Module "deployment.speedometer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ctrl/Servlet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
```